# C++ buffered stream IO

Tags: c++, iostream, buffered

I understand that by default all stream IO supported by C++ is buffered.

This means that data to be output is put into a buffer till it is full and then sent to the output device, similarly for input, the data is read once the buffer is empty...all this is done so that number of expensive system calls could be minimized.

But how to verify this behavior in action. I mean consider the following code

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world\n";
    return 0
}
```

Where does buffering come into picture here ? I know there is buffering happening, but how to explain it? The output is seen instantly on the screen, so what could be a code example to actually see buffered I/O in action ?

Comment: In the case of cout, the buffer is 1 byte. Real buffering comes in to play when you read/write files .

Comment: @Mr.Anubis How do you make that out? And no, it’s not necessarily true.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Well I don't remember the source of that saying but it's some what happens in most case

Comment: @Mr.Anubis There is no case in the standard streams where a buffer of 1 byte is used.  `std::cout` is buffered normally.  (This is different from `stdout` in C, which is line buffered _if_ it is connected to an interactive device, and fully buffered otherwise.  C++ doesn't have the concept of line buffering; using `std::endl` effectively simulates it.)

Comment: @JamesKanze the default case is in fact [C++ streams not being buffered](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/sync_with_stdio), because instead C++ streams write straight to C stdio streams, which is how they can be synchronized. It is only buffered if you desynchronize them explicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following program. `sleep(1)` is used to introduce delay(1 second), I'm using linux, so `sleep` works for me. If you can't make it work, try other ways to delay this program(for example, simple `for` loop). You may also try increasing buffer size(uncomment commented lines of code) if you don't see any buffering effect.

On my OS(`Linux 3.2.0`) and compiler(`g++ 4.6.3`), this program prints "Portion1Portion2" then "Portion3Portion4" and then "Portion5". std::endl [guaranteed to flush](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/endl/) buffer, but as you can see, newline character also works this way for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    // Try uncommenting following lines to increase buffer size
    // char mybuf[1024];
    // cout.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(mybuf, 1024);

    cout << "Portion1";
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Portion2\n";
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Portion3";
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Portion4" << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Portion5" << endl;
    sleep(1);
    cout << "Done!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Even when lines are uncommented?

Answer (score 8):

First, not all iostream is buffered; buffering is handled by the attached
`streambuf`.  In the case of `filebuf` (used by `ifstream` and
`ofstream`), input will read as much as possible, up to the size of the
buffer, and output will flush the buffer on overflow, when an
explicit flush or close occurs, or when the object is destructed (which
implicitly calls close).

The case of `cout` is a bit special, since it is never destructed nor
closes.  There is a guarantee from the system that `flush` will be
called on it at least once after `exit` is called (which is what happens
when you return from `main`).  This means that any output before
returning from main will be flushed; if you're using `cout` in
destructors of static objects, you still need an explicit flush to be
sure.

It's also possible to `tie` an output stream to an input stream; `cout`
is tied to `cin` by default.  In this case, any attempt to input from
the tied stream will flush the output.

The usual convention is to just use `std::endl` instead of simply
outputting `'\n'`; `std::endl` outputs a `'\n'` and then flushes the
stream.  For streams where it is very important for all output to appear
promptly, there is a `unitbuf` flag which can be set, which means that
the stream will be flushed at the end of each `<<` operator.
(`std::cerr` has this set by default.)

Finally, if you want to see the effect of buffering, put something like
`sleep(10)` after your output.  If it output appears immediately, it has been
flushed; if it doesn't it has been buffered, and the flush occured
implicitly after the `sleep`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But it would be great if you could provide me with a code example which consistently works.

Comment: @Arun Which consistently works to do what?  Using `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` will cause a flush at the end of each line.  If you need more than that, `std::cout << std::flush` will flush the output unconditionally.

Comment: I need an example which depicts the role of buffer.
Something like

cout << "Hello world"; //Here output is not seen on console
cout << endl; // Now Hello world is seen on console.

Comment: @Arun So put a delay between those two statements, and you should see that none of the output occurs until after the delay.

Comment: Tried that with no luck on VS2008 and VS2010. The statements are immediately output on the screen. So no evidence of buffering is observed.

Comment: @Arunm So maybe VC2010 uses a very small buffer.  Or changes its buffering policy if the output device is interactive.  (Or, what I think, that the compiler ends up doing unit buffering because of the way it implements synchronization with stdio.)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following code:

```
int main()
{
    for( int i =0 ; i < 10; i ++ )
    {
        cout << i << " ";
        cerr << i << " ";
    }
}
```

The buffered output is usually flushed with the destruction of the stream object, so the code above will print (not always, ofc, but it does for me with gcc 4.6.3)

```
0 1 2 3..9
0 1 2 3..9
```

instead of

```
0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3 .... 9 9
```

[image: my output]

Because the unbuffered `cerr` is printed right away (first sequence) , and buffered `cout` is printed in the end of `main()`.

Comment: @Arun, That's why I said "not always". Buffering is implementation-specific, so you will see different results with different compilers and settings. Sometimes the outputs can even get mixed in a weird order.

Comment: `std::cout` is never destructed, but buffers can be flushed for other reasons.  In this case, both `std::cin` and `std::cerr` are tied to `std::cout`, which means that any IO on one of them will flust `std::cout`.  And `std::cerr` is unit buffered, which means that every `<<` operator flushes it at the end of the operation.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall is there no consistent example which will work always? I tried all the examples in the question, none are working...does this mean for VS2010, it flushes the buffers always?

Comment: @Arun, sorry, I'm unaware of a consistent example. I've posted an image of my output, check the answer please.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall It may (probably) depends on the version of the library.  C++11 requires `std::cout` to be tied to `std::cerr` (in addition to `std::cin`); this means that any output to `std::cerr` will flush `std::cout`, giving "0 0 1 1 ...".  C++03 didn't allow it to be tied, so will typically give "0 1 2... 0 1 2...".

Comment: @JamesKanze, Yes, that sounds plausible. Maybe that also depends on optimization settings.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Optimization has nothing to do with the semantics implemented in the library.  The standard very definitely requires different behavior (with regards to the tie) here.  A C++03 implementation _could_ flush, because it used a buffer of 3 bytes, say, but that would be independent of any output on `std::cerr`.  A C++11 implementation _must_ flush, regardless of buffer size, as soon as anything is output to `std::cerr`.