# delay output in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, output, delay

I want some random characters to be printed to console and then deleted by `"\b"`. After this I want to put my own variable so it will be looking like "randomizing". The problem is that it is happening too fast. I wanted to delay the output by using `usleep` or `sleep` function but when I'm using it, nothing is printed into console.
Short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char chars[]={'a','b','c','g','h','u','p','e','y'};
    for(int i=0; i<8; i++)
    {
        cout << chars[i];
        usleep(200000);
        cout << "\b";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try my little program [slowtty](http://github.com/mojadita/slowtty.git) from github.

It allows you to simulate in a pty the behaviour of an old rs232c line, by delaying the output per character as `stty(1)` command allows to set the baudrate.

You call it with

```
$ slowtty
$ stty 1200
$
```

and the terminal begins to write characters at a slow pace (like a 1200baud line)

Answer (score 4):

Problem is, `std::cout` [is line-buffered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975876/is-stdcout-buffered). It stores all input in a buffer until a newline is encountered (or the program terminates). Use `std::flush` to flush `std::cout` explicitly:

```
cout << chars[i] << flush;
```

---

Notes:

- since C++11, multithreading and time are standardized. That brings the `std::this_thread:sleep_for` function with it, which you should use for a portable >= C++11 program:

  ```
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
  ```

Comment: maybe because of [`cout`, not `std::cout`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) :)

Comment: @ikh I just tried to adjust to the code of the OP, thus assuming a preceding `using` directive.

Answer (score 1):

On many systems output is buffered.

To ensure that what you sent out to `cout` has really been flushed out of buffers you need to call

```
cout.flush();
```

before the sleep