# What does this mean: 'std::cout' is buffered

Tags: stream, buffer, flush

Lately, I was understanding what exactly `buffering` is. And I read that `cout` is buffered. So I got confused. What does it mean that `cout` is buffered? In general, what does it mean when someone says that something is buffered? And what does flushing the *streams(cout/buffer)* mean?
Any example tagged with the answer would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a related post:
[Is std::cout buffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975876/is-stdcout-buffered)

And here's an article that talks about it in more detail:
https://www.programmingincpp.com/flush-the-output-stream-buffer.html

Comment: Thank you so very much, I was struggling to grasp the whole scene happening internally, and now its as clear as crystal.