# C++: Why does this code only work when using '\n'?

Tags: c++, delay

The following C++ code works fine when compiling with g++ on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void wait(){
  int t0 = time(0);
  while(true){
    if(time(0) >= t0 + 1){
      return;
    }
  }
}
int main(){
  while(true){
    cout << "tick\n";  //Line 15
    wait();
  }
}
```

This is the output where one `tick` appears every second:

```
tick
tick
tick
tick
tick
```

However when removing the `\n` in line 15 it seems to just be stuck somewhere and nothing happens.
What exactly is `\n` doing to the code? What do I do if I don't want to print in a new line after every cycle? *(I assume that calling this a bug in C++ would be a bit arrogant and wrong)*

Also, I know that this is probably a very bad way of building a delay function, I'm just messing around a bit.

Comment: It's possible your output window only prints lines, so it's waiting for a newline before printing it. Doesn't mean your 'tick' isn't added to your output stream though.

Comment: It's stuck in the stream's output buffer. On some systems the `'\n'` forces the stream to flush the buffer to the underlying medium, the console in this case. This is done because flushes can be expensive. You generally don't want to flush until you have to, to show the user some output for example .

Comment: Quick better way to to the wait: [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) or it's buddy [`std::this_thread::sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until). Which one you want depends on how you want to wake up, Every period or at a specific time, respectively.

Comment: Here is explained how to use std::flush in similar case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22026751/c-force-stdcout-flush-print-to-screen

Comment: More handy reading: [std::cout won't print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14858262/stdcout-wont-print)

Comment: Removing puts it all on 1 line. Are you sure that you're not seeing the correct output just squished onto the same line?

Comment: And more on `std::cout` buffering : [Is std::cout buffered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975876/is-stdcout-buffered).

Answer (score 10):

It seems that your implementation of `std::cout` writes to the C output stream `stdout`. And `stdout` is by default (when connected to a terminal) *line-buffered*.

Line-buffering means that output is buffered internally, until a newline (`'\n'`) is added to the buffer. Then the buffer is flushed and actually written to the terminal.

---

You can explicitly flush the buffer by using the C++ I/O manipulator `std::flush`, as in

```
cout << "tick" << std::flush;
```

That will immediately flush the buffer and write it to the terminal. But without a newline. To add a newline you could use `std::endl`:

```
cout << "tick" << std::endl;  // Add newline and flush
```

But note that the explicit extra flush isn't needed here, as the newline itself flushes the buffer. Using `std::endl` will therefore first flush the buffer once because of the newline, and then flush the empty buffer because of the explicit flushing semantics.

It's recommended that you don't use `std::flush` (or `std::endl`) unless you really have to. In most cases it's not really needed.

Comment: Adding a bit about `std::flush` and `std::endl` would improve the answer, I believe.

Comment: See also [How does std::flush work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105650/how-does-stdflush-work) for details of when line-buffers are automatically flushed.