# Question std::cout in C++ how exactly does the stream work?

Tags: c++

Say we have:

```cpp
std::cout << "Something";
```

How exactly is this working? I just want to make sure I understand this well and, from what I've been reading, is it okay to say that basically the insertion operator inserts the string literal `"Something"` into the standard output stream?

But what happens after that? Where does the standard output stream lead? Can anyone explain this?

That's basically the only part I don't get: I have the string literal `"Something"` in the standard output stream, but where does the stream lead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technical details vary between the different Operating Systems, but the basics are the same:

Every program has usually 3 standard streams: out (`cout`), in (`cin`), and err (`cerr`) (same as out, but used for errors). Those streams are nothing on their own; they exist to be used by a third party. That third party may be, for example, the terminal. When you execute a program form the terminal, it attaches to the program streams and show their output/request their input in the terminal.

If you wanted to do the same, you could execute a command yourself from your program, and take the out/in/err streams to read or write from/to them.
You have an example of that here: [How do I execute a command and get the output of the command within C++ using POSIX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478898/how-do-i-execute-a-command-and-get-the-output-of-the-command-within-c-using-po)

Edit: When talking about C++, remember that `cout << "anything"` is just syntactic sugar for the function `cout.operator<<("anything")`. And that function "simply" writes to the stream

Comment: Okay but still not exactly what I wanted um just one tiny thing so like, cout << "something"; does that put something right into the stream and then it goes straight into the program or like is there something going into the buffer here?

Comment: About if it is buffered, yes. You'll get a better answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975876/is-stdcout-buffered

Comment: There is a lot of detail missing in this answer, for instance the existence of `std::streambuf` how it is assigned to `std::cin`/`std::cout`/`std::cerr`, and how it is linked to `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`.

Comment: Then how exactly does this go? Does the string get inserted into the stream and then all that goes into the buffer or idk how does it work?

Answer (score -3):

so,'std' is the namespace in which is stored everything found in the standard library , so basically you are saying "hey C++, go to 'std' storage and find cout command and run it" at least I know 'std' is this. and when you are saying using namespace std; you tell the compiler "take everything that's in the std namespace and dump it in the global namespace".
I hope it helped you to understand.

Comment: oh, my bad. I thought you are having problem with std, I'm new to stack you know lol.