No progress in a two thread C++ program to print odd and even elements of a vector
I was asked to implement a program during an interview which spawns 2 threads taking a given input vector, one thread is responsible for only printing the even elements of the vector, and the other the odd elements. This is how I implemented the code -
std::mutex mu_vec;
std::condition_variable m_cv;
bool odd = true;

void print_odd(const std::vector<int>& vals, int &id){
    while(true){
        std::unique_lock sl(mu_vec);
        m_cv.wait(sl, []{return odd; });
        if(id >= vals.size()){
            sl.unlock();
            break;
        }
        if(vals[id] & 1){
            std::cout << vals[id] << "\t";
            id++;
        }
        else{
            odd = false;
            sl.unlock();
            m_cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

void print_even(const std::vector<int>& vals, int &id){
    while(true){
        std::unique_lock sl(mu_vec);
        m_cv.wait(sl, []{return !odd; });
        if(id >= vals.size()){
            sl.unlock();
            break;
        }
        if((vals[id] & 1) == 0){
            std::cout << vals[id] << "\t";
            id++;
        }
        else{
            odd = true;
            sl.unlock();
            m_cv.notify_one();
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    std::vector<int> vals{5, 10, 4, 7, 1, 6};
    int id = 0;
    std::jthread odd_printer(print_odd, std::cref(vals), std::ref(id));
    std::jthread eve_printer(print_even, std::cref(vals), std::ref(id));
    return 0;
}

I tried debugging with using print statements within both print_odd and print_even functions but the program is showing no stdout and executing the code just hangs indefinitely.
Please suggest how do I debug further or what is the problem in the current program.

Personally, I'd avoid holding a mutex while doing IO.  But that isn't your problem.

You are not seeing any output because the output is line-buffered and you never write a '\n'. Just replace the "\t" with a '\n' and you will see that output is written but the threads hang afterwards. A debugger should show you where each thread hangs.
From looking at it, your condition variable wait condition does not check that the sequence has been fully processed. Threads should stop waiting when the id reaches the end of the vector. Something like this:
        m_cv.wait(sl, [&]{return odd || id >= vals.size(); });
        if(id >= vals.size()){
            sl.unlock();
            m_cv.notify_one();
            break;
        }

and the same for the other thread.
There are other quality issues (such as using int to index a vector instead of using std::size_t) and I think there are easier ways to implement this code, but that should solve the issue.

\n doesn't necessarily flush, that is an implementation details. Output a std::flush, call std::cout.flush() or replace the trailing \n with std::endl if you want to explicitly flush a buffered output. If \n flushed, there would be no need for std::endl to exist.

@FrançoisAndrieux C++ standard 17 section 29.4.3 [narrow.stream.objects]: The object cout controls output to a stream buffer associated with the object stdout …. C standard 99 section 7.19.3 Files paragraph 7: the standard input and standard
output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device. Ergo: If stdout is connected to a terminal, as is the case here, it is line-buffered or unbuffered. Therefore '\n' is sufficient.

@FrançoisAndrieux See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26975876/is-stdcout-buffered and the links contained within. Stroustrup seems to agree that endl should be avoided

What constitutes an interactive device is implementation defined. If the intention is to flush, calling flush is the fully portable solution.

@FrançoisAndrieux If you are wondering why you don't see any output on your terminal and it's because your C/C++ implementation doesn't recognize your terminal as an interactive device, get yourself a better implementation.
